# Remove Json specific node

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, json.net, object-to-string

during run time I'd like to print JSon to log but censor one of its fields.
I use JSon.Net and have all the attributes, for example

```
    public Class Terms
    {
        [JsonProperty("Term")]
        string term

        [JsonProperty("SecretTerm")]
        string SecretTerm

        public string toCensoredString()
        {
         // I need to get a JSON string with only the regular term and not the secret
         var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
         // .....
        }
    }
```

What will be the best way to eliminate specific field in runtime in my new ToCensoredString() function?

Comment: Could you give more code? it is still not clear much?

Comment: Also, how are you doing your serialization ?

Comment: added some example of the code...

Comment: I'd like that my generated Json request will contain only one field out of the two above, in that way I could print it to log cause it will be without the secret part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest approach is to use the `JsonIgnore` attribute.

If I create a `Terms` object like this:

```
Terms terms = new Terms() { SecretTerm = "Secret", Term = "Not secret" };
```

And if `SecretTerm` looks like this:

```
[JsonIgnore]
[JsonProperty("SecretTerm")]
public string SecretTerm { get; set; }
```

Your serialized Json will look like this:

```
{
    "Term": "Not secret"
}
```

If you want more fine-grained control you will have to create a custom converter.

**Edit:**

To more selectively output the object, you need the custom converter:

```
class TermsConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Terms) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Terms terms = (Terms)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Term");
        writer.WriteValue(terms.Term);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

When serializing, you would do this:

```
var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new TermsConverter());
```

You'll note that I have left the `ReadJson` unimplemented - I don't think it's necessary as you can easily deserialize a `Terms` object without using a converter. In this case the `SecretTerm` property would simply be empty.

By using the converter you won't need the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the `SecretTerm` property.

Comment: Thanks.but JsonIgnore will always filter this field right? I want to filter this field only in specific usage, but the rest of the clients should get the field..

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your answer! I guess I could make neater if WriteJson will be generic and go over the JsonProperty to get the display name. and on that I'll add new custom attribute [Censored] and will ignore those fields?